# Finding Values from a form control Outside Forms

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

i was wondering if it is possible to get the values from my form controls. Through x++ code from my class or my table method ?

I am iterating through my form, and i want to get all the names and values. I got the names but not values, please help thanks.

```
if (_formControlId)
{
    formGroupControl = _formRun.design().control(_formControlId);
}
else
{
    formGroupControl = _formRun.design();
}
// Finding children
controlCount = formGroupControl.controlCount();
for (i = 1; i <= controlCount; i++)
{
    formControl = formGroupControl.controlNum(i);
    // Fill MainTable
    if(formControl is formTabPageControl)
    {
        if(formControl.HierarchyParent()    == formControl.HierarchyParent("TabHeader"))
        {
            mainTopicId++;
            GloDataMainTopics.Topic     = formControl.labeltext();
            GloDataMainTopics.TopicId   = int2str(mainTopicId);
            GloDataMainTopics.insert();

            newParentTopicId = GloDataMainTopics.TopicId;
        }
    }
    // Fill SubTable
    if(formControl is formGroupControl)
    {
        newParentTopicId = this.fillGroupControls(formControl, _parentTopicId);
    }
    if (!newParentTopicId)
        newParentTopicId = _parentTopicId;
    //Fill Lines
    if (formControl is FormStringControl    || formControl is FormReferenceGroupControl ||
        formControl is FormCheckBoxControl  || formControl is FormComboBoxControl       ||
        formControl is FormWindowControl    || formControl is FormDateControl           ||
        formControl is FormRealControl      || formControl is FormIntControl)
        {
            this.fillLineFields(formControl, newParentTopicId, j);

            /*
            this.fillTabPagePurchase(formControl, newParentTopicId);
            this.fillTabPageGeneral(formControl, newParentRecId);
            */
            //info(strFmt("MainTopics '%1', %2", formControl.name(), j ));
        }

    if (formControl.isContainer())
    {
        this.findNodes(_formRun, formControl.id(), newParentTopicId);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/83599

Comment: This is an unusual request, could you shed some light on your use case?
Are you talking about dialog fields or saving form fields to the database?
If possible show some code.

Comment: I am using the standard EcoResProductDetailsExtended, and then i have created a class which recursivly iterates through all the controls. I can get the names and etc. on the controls but not the values.

Comment: Could you show some of the code that you use to access the controls and get their names?

Comment: [Same question](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/184017) in AX community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.  Bear in mind that some control's values are stored in `.text()`, `valueStr()`, etc and not in `.value()` but you'll figure it out.

```
Object      control;
control = formControl; // I'm assuming this is your control you're using

if (SysTest::hasMethod(control, identifierStr(text)))
{
    text = control.text();
    info(strFmt("Text found is '%1'", text));
}

if (SysTest::hasMethod(control, identifierStr(value)))
{
    value = control.value();
    info(strFmt("Value found is '%1'", value));
}
```

Here is a blog post I did that shows how to recurse over all of the form's controls. You can take the inner-method and put it on the form's method, then call it at run-time and just add the extra `SysTest::` blocks and it should give you a quick working proof of concept of every control on the form and value/text/etc.

http://www.alexondax.com/2014/05/how-to-use-recursion-to-loop-over-form.html

Comment: Even with this function, my values are empty

Comment: I also tried the link, even when i try the links function. It comes up empty.

Comment: I think you're doing something wrong then or not providing enough detail. I tested this and it worked for me. I added a `StringEdit` to a form and a button with this code in it, then typed some data into the `StringEdit` (without AutoDeclaration on) and was able to enumerate the data.

Comment: (I am doing this in a class) All my controls are empty except the checkbox comes up as "No". And when i try use the same command in the form. The value pops up. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: My test is with a form, not a class. But I think it's because you're iterating over the static form, and not the actual running form.  Try `_formRun.form().design()` instead of `_formRun.design()`.

Comment: No you were right, from the beginning it was because i have'nt declared my which values i got . text() valueStr() etc. Thank you !

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark the answer as accepted so that others don't try and solve it for you.